# Overflow doesn't show all the content (cut)

Tags: html, css, overflow, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify and I want to make a scrollable [stepper](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers) inside a dialog.

Here is a codepen

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OqWQdy

I applied my class `stepper-scrollable-content` on the `v-stepper-items`

```
.stepper-scrollable-content {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
}


<v-stepper-items class="stepper-scrollable-content">
  <v-stepper-content step="1">
    ...
  </v-stepper-content>
</v-stepper-items>
```

The problem is when I'm on mobile or when I resize the browser's window vertically the overflow doesn't show all the content. I can't see all the form inputs. The overflow is cut.

[image: overflow cut]

How can I fix it ?

Comment: its been hidden under the Continue Cancel section. You need to set some min-heights

Comment: @GifCo can you show me how you do that by using my codepen ? because I tried to set some min-heights but there is no change

Comment: set min-heght: 300px on <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent scrollable max-width="600px">

Comment: @GifCo it not working

Comment: I dont know how you set styles with the library you are using but it works in dev tools.

Comment: you need to use content-class ... see here: https://codepen.io/GifCo/pen/XGpqVX

Comment: It seems to work. I'll try tomorrow. But what is this content-class ? I never see it

Comment: Not really sure I dont use Vue. But apparently on v-dialog you cant just set a class="myclass" you have to use content-class="myclass"

Comment: @GifCo, by applying a `min-height` on `v-dialog`, when the height of the viewport is below `300px` its top and bottom get trimmed without the possibility to scroll to them, so both `v-dialog` header and footer become inaccessible.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu yes and when the viewport is below 10px you cant see anything! lol not even the oldest iPhone has a viewport height  < 300px; Kind of pointless to style for that use case

Comment: @Gif, you'd be surprised how many things one can do on a Wear. Anyway, being a developer, I try not to discriminate and code for as many cases as possible.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I dont think anyone fills out forms on a watch especially a form like this. If you are saying you go around setting styles for every screen that has ever existed I cant imagine you get anything done. Working smart is not discriminating whatever that was supposed to mean.

Comment: @GifCo, considering the question's screenshot, accessibility on small height viewports is ***the main concern*** here. While my answer works on viewports with height of `200px` and above (limitation coming from vuetify `v-dialog` itself), your suggestion only works above `300px`. I haven't ventured an opinion on how often this problem occurs in real life or how useful it will be to OP. I only stated your suggestion has accessibility problems at heights between `200px` and `300px`, which appears to be *true* and which is ***not** true* for default `v-dialog`s.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Im not going to argue with you. The original iPhone had a vertical resolution of 480px thats about the smallest device you could own other than a smart watch which is usually around 320x320 for older models. If you are trying to design this for ANY resolution your solution is also wrong as it doesn't work under 200px. So I really dont know what you are trying to prove here. Anyway happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit the height of your `.v-card.` you'll need to do it on the `.v-card` itself:

```
.stepper-scrollable-content {
   overflow: auto;
   max-height: calc(100% - 71px);
}
.v-card {
   max-height: 340px;
}
```

Updated pen: https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/wOgXYM

Comment: Thank you, it works exactly how I want ! If i do just `max-height: calc(100% - 71px);` on the scrollable content it works. But I don't know what is exactly. I never used calc.

Comment: @John - MDN: [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), W3C: [#calc-notation](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-notation).